# Interface Segregation in Java CRUD

Tags: java, interface, design-principles

I have classes which are dependent on an interface which defines methods CREATE , READER , UPDATE and DELETE

However some of my implementation do not have option for CREATE

I believe it is not best practice to force those classes to implement CREATE method .

How can I best implement my interface so that it is not mandatory to implement CREATE in some classes .

Comment: Maybe you can create several interfaces `C` `R` `U` and `D`. Then CRUD would extend those 4 interfaces. It is also acceptable to implement the method and throw a `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Comment: I used UnsupportedOperationException as only one of the implementation did not have create method . Thanks .

Answer (score 2):

the only possible way I think is having another class (`ClassA`) which have `CREATE` method `but not implements the interface` now the target class (`TClass`) which implements the interface(`CURDInterface`) can have not the CREATE method if extends from `ClassA`:

```
interface CRUDInterface{     
  public void Create();
  public SomeType Read();
  public void Update();
  public void Delete();
} 

class ClassA{
  public void Create() {
    //do something;
  }
}

class TClass extends ClassA implements CRUDInterface{
  public SomeType Read() {
    //do something;
  }
  public void Update() {
    //do something;
  }
  public void Delete() {
    //do something;
  }
}
```